# Href to checked input radio

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have this code and I want after click to a href checked to radio box 
code:

```
 <p><a href=""><?php echo $result['answer1'];?><input type="radio" value="1" class='rgt' name='test1'/></a></p>
 <p><a href=""><?php echo $result['answer2'];?><input type="radio" value="2" class='rgt' name='test2'/></a></p>
 <p><a href=""><?php echo $result['answer3'];?><input type="radio" value="3" class='rgt' name='test3'/></a></p>
```

How can do it?

Comment: Do you need to uncheck other radio buttons, when one is selected? Based on your code - i would say you need checkboxes (if multiple selection is possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<p><a href="">111111111111111<input type="radio" value="1" class='rgt' name='test1'/></a></p>
 <p><a href="">2222222222222222<input type="radio" value="2" class='rgt' name='test2'/></a></p>
 <p><a href="">3333333333333333<input type="radio" value="3" class='rgt' name='test3'/></a></p>
</div>
```

(all is placed in container, for easier targeting)

JS:

```
container=document.getElementById('container');
links=container.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(i=0;i<links.length;i++) {

    links[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){

e.preventDefault();  

        if(this.childNodes[1].checked == true) {

        this.childNodes[1].checked = false;
        }
        else {
             this.childNodes[1].checked =true;
        }


    });


}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ydu6h8vd/